# Chartist.js in Vue using typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, chartist.js

I am running into an issue of loading 'vue-chartist' module into my root file (boot.ts).

I have installed module using 'npm install vue-chartist --save'

Every time when I try to import 'vue-chartist' module it cannot be recognised.

[Please see attached print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgVg7.jpg)

I am using template:
'dotnet new –install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*'
'dotnet new vue'

- ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0
- Vue.js 2
- TypeScript

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using typescript, the transpiler is looking for the type definition of vue-chartist which is not provided in the package nor available in @types/vue-chartist. This leaves you with two options, create your own type definition file or tell the transpiler to "forget about it". for the second option, create a new file vue-chartist.d.ts somewhere in your project (I recommend src/typings folder) and put the following content in it:

```
declare module "vue-chartist";
```

Note that while this will make the transpiler work it will not git you actual typing. Also, it may take a little bit or perhaps a restart for your IDE to recognize the typing file. The build should start working right away though.